# Misbehaviour in glassfish when logging in trough firefox

Tags: firefox, glassfish

I work with glassfish on a daily basis (currently with Firefox 23) and I had never come across with this before. When I log in into admin console (`localhost:4848`), glassfish redirects me to this site https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/s/glassfish/productmsg.html, and there's nothing else I can do. I've already tried closing firefox, glassfish and I even turned my computer off and on but the problem persists.
[image: What shows the site]

On the other hand, I tried the same thing with IE10, and it works perfectly fine.
Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've already solved it. I cleaned up cookies, cache and active sessions (`Ctrl + Shift + Del`), but I still have no idea what was happening.